# Getting awk working properly in a for loop

Tags: bash

I am trying to extract the second column out of 22 different files. I get a correct output when working on a single file but when in a loop, in each file it concatenates in series the 2 column of several different files in one. Can anybody please help me.

```
for i in f*
do
    awk '{print $2}' f* > a_$i
done
```

Comment: instead of putting the output of every extracted column of every file in a different file

Comment: The `f*` glob on the `awk` command line is having `awk` operate on every file during every iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your command like,

```
for i in f*
do
    awk '{print $2}' "$i" > "a_$i"
done
```

One-liner,

```
for i in f*; do awk '{print $2}' "$i" > "a_$i"; done
```

You need to replace `f*` in your awk command with `$i` which stores the current  file name.

Answer (score 1):

This does what you want:

```
awk '{print $2 >"a_"FILENAME}' f*
```

For every file starting with the letter `f`, this writes its second columns to a new file that starts with `a_`.

The output files have the same number of rows as the input but the output has only the second column.

Note that the above works because `>` means something somewhat different in `awk` than it does in shell.

#### Example

Suppose that we have a series of files like:

```
$ cat f1
One 1
One 11
```

Now, let's run the `awk` command:

```
$ awk '{print $2 >"a_"FILENAME}' f*
```

When this is done, there are a series of `a_*` files in the directory, such as:

```
$ cat a_f1
1
11
```

Comment: This should work in standard POSIX `awk` as well; both `FILENAME` and using `> name` with `print` are supported.

Comment: @chepner Thanks for that info: answer updated to remove mention of GNU.

Comment: Thanks a great deal but your method did only  work on the first file and not the subsequent ones and wasn't much different also when i put it in a for loop

Comment: @sknimo Curious.  It works fine for me on not just the first but all the files.  What OS are you using?  What version of `awk`?

Comment: @John1024, I am using Ubuntu 14.10 but I am new to linux so the fault could also be from my end. I have no idea how to check the version of awk that I am using but since i installed it not too long ago I want to believe it's the latest version. I now find myself in a field where i would be dealing with large data, can you pls recomend a book which would help me get on a good start with shell scripting?

Comment: @sknimo In that case, your `awk` should behave like mine.  (If you were on, say, Mac OSX, that could explain the problem.)  As for tutorials, there are many.  Grymoire's tutorials are dated but I like them for [awk](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) and [sed](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html).  I expect that his [shell tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sh.html) is good was well.